# Target a single instance of a class element

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-selectors, gallery

I have a list of classified ads with multiple images.I have php creating the thumbs and I simply want to do a image gallery where clicking on the thumbs change the image in the main div. My problem is that there is a looping situation with multiple ads, so I have a problem targeting the main div since the .class attibute target all instances of the class.
A div '.annonce' englobes the images in separate divs `.annoncephoto1`, `.annoncephoto2` etc...
The images have the same name except for the prefix 120__ or 600__ depending if it is intended for the main window or the thumb window. So how to target the current main div?
Here is my javascript codes which works but changes the image in all the main div on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.thumbs img').click(function(){
    $('.bigimage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('120__','600__'));    
});
</script>
```

Thanks to  Lazarevic Ivan for this code base that I found on stackoverflow.
As asked here is the html:

```
foreach($results as $book){
$specialtexts = preg_replace($patterns,$reps,$book[8]);  
echo '<div class="annonces">';
if ($book[9])
{
$p = new phMagick();
$imageUrl = $p->onTheFly('annonce/' . $book[10], 120);
$imageUrl = $p->onTheFly('annonce/' . $book[10], 600);
echo '<div class="annoncephoto1" id="id1" ><img class="bigimage" src="' . $imageUrl . '" /></div>';
} 
echo '<div class="thumbs" >';
if ($book[10])
{$p = new phMagick();
$imageUrl = $p->onTheFly('annonce/' . $book[10], 600);
$imageUrl = $p->onTheFly('annonce/' . $book[10], 120);
?>
<?php echo '<img src="' . $imageUrl . '" />';
}
```

etc...
$imageUrl = $p->onTheFly resizes the image if the image doesn't already exist.

Here is a simplified jsfiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/qwhat/trrwygdv/. Clicking the two images on the right should change the bigger image immediately to the left.

Comment: can you share the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a jQuery event handler , `this` is the current element that event is being triggered on.

You use the current element to create a traverse that depends on the html structure.

Try:

```
$(function(){

    $('.thumbs img').click(function(){
        var $bigImage = $(this).parent().prev().find('.bigimage');
        $bigImage.attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('120__','600__'));    
    });

});
```

Your code doesn't show closing of `<div class="annonces">`. If that is being properly closed in the loop you can use:

```
var $bigImage = $(this).closest('.annonces').find('.bigimage');
```

Comment: Thanks. That didn't work. As you said, it must be my html stucture. Here is a test page: [link](http://www.lagrandiere-immobilier.fr/jvtest.php). I tried both of your solutions. I do believe that my annonces div closes correctly

Comment: you didn't mention you are using a plugin already, use plugin API event callbacks to do this

Comment: What plugin? I am not using shadowbox on the first two thumbs to try to implement this. It will eventually replace the shadowbox effect. If not shadowbox, i don't understand.

Comment: well I clicked on shadowbox elements. You are getting error thrown and I'm not interested in chasing around all your files to figure out where this script is. Create a simplified demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here is a simplified jsfiddle version: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qwhat/fborbgr0/). Clicking the two images on the right should change the bigger image immediately to the left.

Comment: OK, I made a typo easily noticed in browser console errors. `$bigimage.attr` should be `$bigImage.attr`  http://jsfiddle.net/fborbgr0/1/

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl  Works on site but not on jsfiddle?? Please explain How do you see the browser console error.

Comment: hit F12 will open console